# Why can't my automated Test click on this button?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, coded-ui-tests

In my hand-coded CODEDUI test I have a Button on a web page I want to click,  whose mark-up looks like this:

```
<button onclick="window.location='/create-this#/authenticate'">Create This</button>
```

This code performs the click, note I have already proved that the proper button instance is returned and the var BTN is the correct control.

```
               btn.EnsureClickable();
               btn.SetFocus();
               Mouse.Click(btn);
```

I can even see the attempted click happening on that part of the browser window, so I know it's "finding" and "navigating" to the control.

Here's the error message/stack trace:

[image]

The inner exception  HResult is: -2147467259

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  IE and Chrome remember the last monitor they were closed, as well as the browser size.  When CodedUI Launches the browser it opens on the last known monitor.

I test with three monitors and have found that the two larger (non laptop) monitors case click fails in automated test (one more than the other).  All I had to do to fix this was open and close the browser on the main monitor (of the laptop) and the tests ran fine.

This implies that the monitor drivers, resolution and other factors play into test failures somehow. I am assuming that CodedUI is only calling lower level "things" to do it's job and has little or no concept on actual widths of windows it's playing against.